# Create empty element with DOM's createElement

Tags: javascript, html, dom, svg, createelement

The problem is that I want to create svg file dynamically with JavaScript. But when drawing path, it don't render to the screen (last 2~3 hours I'm looking for the problem)... And here is it... when creating element with `document.createElement`, we get `<element> </element>`. But the path element has to be created as empty element - `<path .../>`.
So. How can I create empty elements using `document.createElement`? Or maybe I can't do that with `document.createElement` and have to use JQuery for doing this?

```
let b1b2 = document.createElement('path');
b1b2.setAttribute('d', 'M0 0 L100 100');
b1b2.setAttribute('fill', 'none');
b1b2.setAttribute('stroke', 'red');
b1b2.setAttribute('stroke-width', '5');

<path d="M0 0 L100 100" fill="none" stroke="red" stroke-width="5"></path>
```

Comment: what's wrong with what you have? you might need the svg namespace to get it to display right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SVG have a special namespace requirement. You need to use [document.createElementNS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createElementNS):

```
document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg', 'path');
```

Example:

```js
let b1b2 = document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg', 'path');

b1b2.setAttribute('d', 'M0 0 L100 100');
b1b2.setAttribute('fill', 'none');
b1b2.setAttribute('stroke', 'red');
b1b2.setAttribute('stroke-width', '5');

document.getElementById('svg').appendChild(b1b2);
```

```html
<svg id="svg"></svg>
```

Comment: I think you probably also want to use `Element.setAttributeNS()`.

Comment: When using `.createElementNS(...)` only on `path`, I get the same problem. But. When I use it on the `svg` too, then all works perfectly. Thank you for your answer :)